# In Scala how do you call toMap on a List of a case class?

Tags: scala

I would like to be able to call toMap on a List of a case class:

```
case class Properties(name: String, value: String)

val lst = List(Properties("name1", "val1"))
lst.toMap
```

This doesn't work because there is no implicit evidence
`Properties <:< (T,U)`
so I map the list to a List[(String,String)] then call toMap.
Is there anyway of doing this without the map?

Comment: I am pretty sure this was asked before and I answered it, but I can't find it. - Anyways, you may provide a fake evidence but that may cause more trouble than good. I would just use a `view` / `iterator` to collapse the `map` call.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez was just curious to see if it could be done somehow using <:< evidence

Comment: @SwiftMango Do you know how to make one?

Comment: Actually it is not possible to do that. It's a sealed class. You should use view and map to the tuple

Answer (score 1):

In general you're going to need a conversion from your case class to a `Tuple2`.

If your `case class` happens to have 2 fields and you want to key on the first field, there's an already available conversion: the companion object's `unapply` method:

```scala
case class Properties(name: String, value: String)

val lst = List(Properties("name1", "val1"))
lst.view.flatMap(Properties.unapply).toMap
```

Comment: This definitely works, but `lst.view.map(p => (p.name, p.value)).toMap` is probably more straightforward to read and involves similar amounts of typing and computation.

Comment: That is actually how I did it. I was curious to see if there was some clever way of doing it with an implicit evidence but because Tuple2 is final there is no way to do it.